# Can a pilot use legal psychoactive cannabinoids?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

How do the FAA and airline companies treat pilots using substances like [Delta-8-Tetrahydrocannabinol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-8-Tetrahydrocannabinol) on their down time? Like CBD, Delta-8-THC is a legal derivative from marijuana.

Comment: Taxiway delta 8 is ok though.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/59795/62)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delta-8-Tetrahydrocannabinol (Delta-8-THC, Δ8-THC) is a cannabinoid found in the cannabis plant. It has psychoactive properties; the effects are less potent but comparable.

Delta 8 THC metabolites trigger many drug tests looking for Delta 9 THC metabolites. These compounds are chemically similar.

Whoever needs to pass a drug test (pilots included) should not take them.

Comment: I made a mistake of  saying it had no psychoactive properties but I corrected it before there was an answer.

Comment: Yep, if you want to fly, stick to alcohol.  In Canada, pot is legal now, but Transport Canada policy is zero tolerance and will still ground you if you have any THC or THC derivatives in your system.

Comment: There was a fatal train crash in London in 1991 when the driver failed to stop in time at a terminal station and the report said the driver may have been using cannabis. An expert witness said that this drug impairs time and distance estimation skills, and, paradoxically, causes the the user to feel that they are improved.